# I'm trying to use Ajax to capture facebook data and write it to a text file named test.txt

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, mongodb

I followed the second answer on this page, except that I replaced the complicated looking php part with a simple empty text file named test.txt. I don't get any error messages, but the file remains empty (I don't seem to be able to write the data to my file; does anyone have an idea why? Better yet, I would love to write the data directly to a mongodb database!   [Getting userdata using Facebook Login Javascript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984611/getting-userdata-using-facebook-login-javascript-sdk/20984932#20984932)

My code is as follows:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '753236104711327',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });

FB.login(function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
 console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
   console.log(response);

$.ajax(
{
type : 'POST',
data : response, //all data 
url : 'test.txt',
success :   function()
{
console.log(response.name)
    }
});

});

} else {
 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
}
}, {scope: 'user_birthday, friends_birthday, basic_info, user_about_me,   friends_about_me, user_education_history, friends_education_history, user_hometown, friends_hometown, user_interests, friends_interests, user_location, friends_location, user_questions, friends_questions, user_relationships, friends_relationships, user_relationship_details, friends_relationship_details, user_religion_politics, friends_religion_politics, user_work_history, friends_work_history'});
};

(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here is sending a POST request to a text file, which doesn't really make sense, unless you have your server set up to capture the request.

The `data:` part of the `$.ajax()` call converts the object it is given (in this case your `response` object) into a query string, which is then sent as part of the request.

It's almost as if you had typed this into your address bar:

`http://your.website.net/path/to/test.txt?responseProperty1=someData&responseProperty2=someOtherData`

and `test.txt` doesn't have any way of dealing with the query string since it's just an empty text file.

You're probably going to have to use a server-side language like PHP to write the data to your file. You would then send the ajax request to a file on the server that would be able to handle the request parameters:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: response,
  url: 'handle_response.php',
  success: function() {
    // it worked
  }
});
```

I'm not great at PHP and maybe you'd rather use something else anyways so I'll leave it there, but I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can't write data to a text file with Javascript. If you want to write the data to a text file, or to Mongo, you need to send it to a server and have the server handle writing to a file or to a database